# LINQ - How do I guarantee only one matching entry returned satisfying a certain criteria?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Let's say I have a SQL table that represents college courses:

```
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  Id    |     StudentId    |     CourseName   |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  1     |        15        |    Biology 101   |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  2     |        21        |    English 201   |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  3     |        38        |    History 301   |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  4     |        41        | Anthropology 401 |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  5     |        15        |   Graphics 210   |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
|  6     |        21        |  Physics Lab B   |
```

It has a student Id that represents that this student is taking this college course. As you can see, a student can take multiple courses.

Now, let's say that I have a list of student Ids like so: `[15, 21]`

I want to write a LINQ statement that will give me *only one* course (It can be the first but it doesn't have to be) for each student id in my list.

So, in my example, I will get courses 1 and 2 back.  But it could be courses 2 and 5 or courses 5 and 6. It doesn't matter. I just need to guarantee that one and only one course for *each* student id in my list is returned. I am also guaranteed that a course will exist for student id.

Short of writing direct SQL, how would I do this in Entity Framework/LINQ?

Comment: How is this table represented in code? What have you tried so far? Because it should be pretty simple, using `Where()` and `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: I would suggest using `GroupBy` to combine courses a student is taking. If you are trying to do this using `Include` from a student table, it isn't easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity framework Select first item in group that satisfies condition or just first item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462671/entity-framework-select-first-item-in-group-that-satisfies-condition-or-just-fir)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Kind of. I'd like to avoid having to load back all the data from the DB and then processing it. This is a huge table and I'm trying to make it more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataBase db = new DataBase()
            {
                students = new List<Students>() {
                    new Students() { Id = 1, StudentId = 15, CourseName = "Biology 101"},
                    new Students() { Id = 2, StudentId = 21, CourseName = "English 201"},
                    new Students() { Id = 3, StudentId = 38, CourseName = "History 301"},
                    new Students() { Id = 4, StudentId = 41, CourseName = "Anthropology 401"},
                    new Students() { Id = 5, StudentId = 15, CourseName = "Graphics 210"},
                    new Students() { Id = 6, StudentId = 21, CourseName = "Physics Lab B"}
                }
            };

            List<int> searchIds = new List<int>() { 15, 21 };

            List<Students> results = db.students.Where(x =>  searchIds.Contains(x.StudentId))
                .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
                .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();

        }
    }
    public class DataBase
    {
        public List<Students> students { get;set;}
    }
    public class Students
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oooh, this looks like what I want. Just as a clarification, when you created a class `Students`, do you mean `Courses`?

Comment: It is just a name.